# Problem loading backup Access App, "The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID"

Tags: app, microsoft-access

This relates to an Access App that I designed in Access 2013 and was hosted on my institution's Microsoft Office 365 / Sharepoint site. I had saved a version of the app for backup, which created an `*.app` file. I am now stuck trying to load the app to the Sharepoint site and am getting the error shown in the attached image.  [image: Error message trying to load the .app file]. The error message is "The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID."

I am quite new to Sharepoint, Office 365, etc. but am unable to figure out a workaround for this problem. Here is what I've tried:

- I've deleted the app that was backed up, both from my Sharepoint site and from the recycle bin. (Don't know if it matters, but when I saved it, I saved it with a different name than the app originally had.)
- I learned that the `.app` file contents can be explored by renaming with a `.zip` extension. I tried unzipping, editing the manifest file to change the version number, and rezipping, but that didn't work. Since I really don't understand the nature of the error, I'm not surprised this didn't work or if I weren't to have edited the manifest file correctly.
- I tried creating a sub-site on my personal Sharepoint area and adding the app to that site, but with the same error.

So, I'm stuck at this point. [Here is a link to the `.app` file in case that is useful](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxLNnjMk2r_qdTBuM0N5OXJkWW8/edit?usp=sharing). Thank you!

- PS: I notice now that I saved the `.app` file in a Goolge Drive folder, and when I click on the link above, it shows me the contents of the .app file. Is it possible that by saving to a Google Drive folder, the contents were corrupted via the sync process? Just throwing that out there.

Comment: He is a help page for [creating an Access app package](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-an-access-app-package-HA102749784.aspx). As a newbie, I don't understand the deployment options. However, it appears that for my own backup purposes option #3, "Save Database As New", is the only option that works for me for backup purposes. When I use the "Snapshot" option, I'm unable to load the app on my own sharepoint site, even after trying to delete it, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. Increment the version, or, in rare cases,
2. Change the ProductID in the AppManifest.xml.